# How to send form values using uploadify without selecting a file?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i am using Uplodify plugin to upload video file and form data(some values),in this case i want to store form data without selecting a video file?   I found that submit is a ancher link so ,how to find  video file is exist or not. it should work without select file

This is my working code:

```
<form>
Firstname<input type="firstname" name="firstname" id="firstname"  >
    Lastname<input type="lastname" name="lastname" id="lastname"  >
Upload file: <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
<p><a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload')">Submit</a></p>

</form>

<script>
$('#file_upload').uploadify({

'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
'uploader' : 'new.php',
'method'   : 'post',
'auto'      :false,
'onQueueComplete' : function(queueData) {
    window.location.replace("success.php?success=uploaded");
},
'onUploadStart' : function(file) {

    $('#file_upload').uploadify('settings','formData',{
        'fname': $('input#firstname').val(),
        'lname': $('input#lastname').val()

    });
}

// Your options here
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your anchor simply calls javascript that processes: `Upload file: <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />` you can simply use PHP to check if anything has been selected by the input and then execute javascript and form acording to your needs.